# SQLServery : List all Order by a Client , Multiple Joins to the same Table Issue

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to list all the order done with every customer , So if a certain customer had passed 6 order then we need to list order1 | Order2| order3| ...

I have a table called Order where we have the Client Id , I am using SqlServer 2008 R2 , I have tried different approach but with no success , they run for ever and never gave a result :s , Here my lates try :

```
SELECT    convert(varchar(1),isnull(user.Order.OrderId,'')) +' | '+ convert(varchar(1),isnull(Order_1.OrderId,'')) +' | '+convert(varchar(1),isnull(Order_2.OrderId,'')) +' | '+convert(varchar(1),isnull(Order_3.OrderId,'')) +'  |  '+convert(varchar(1),isnull(Order_4.OrderId,'')) +'  |  '+convert(varchar(1),isnull(Order_5.OrderId,'')) as OrderIdList,   
                   user.client.kdnr 
FROM         user.Order 
left outer JOIN   user.Order AS Order_1 ON user.Order.clientnr = Order_1.clientnr AND        Order_1.OrderId <> user.Order.OrderId and Order.orderDate < Order_1.orderDate
left outer JOIN   user.Orderold AS Order_2 ON user.Order.clientnr = Order_2.clientnr   AND Order_2.OrderId not in ( user.Order.OrderId , Order_1.OrderId ) and Order_1.orderDate < Order_2.orderDate
left outer JOIN   user.Orderold AS Order_3 ON user.Order.clientnr = Order_3.clientnr AND Order_3.OrderId not in ( user.Order.OrderId , Order_1.OrderId, Order_2.OrderId ) and Order_1.orderDate < Order_2.orderDate
left outer JOIN   user.Orderold AS Order_4 ON user.Order.clientnr = Order_4.clientnr AND Order_4.OrderId not in ( user.Order.OrderId , Order_1.OrderId, Order_2.OrderId, Order_3.OrderId ) and Order_2.orderDate < Order_3.orderDate
left outer JOIN   user.Orderold AS Order_5 ON user.Order.clientnr = Order_5.clientnr AND Order_5.OrderId not in ( user.Order.OrderId , Order_1.OrderId, Order_2.OrderId, Order_3.OrderId, Order_4.OrderId ) and Order_3.orderDate < Order_4.orderDate
INNER JOIN   user.client ON Order_1.clientnr = user.client.kdnr
group by client.kdnr  ,user.client.name1,  user.client.firstname,   user.Order.OrderId,  Order_1.OrderId,Order_1.Ordernr,Order_2.OrderId ,Order_3.OrderId,Order_4.OrderId,Order_5.OrderId `
```

Does any body have an dea how would I do that Correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By **using XML capabilities** of SQL Server 2005 and above you can easily and efficiently **generate comma separated values**.

Try this (adjust according to your table and column names):

```
-- Sample tables
declare @Customer table
(
  CustomerId int,
  Name varchar(50)
)

declare @Order table
(
  OrderId int,
  CustomerId int
)

-- Sample data
insert into @Customer (CustomerId, Name) values (1, 'Alice')
insert into @Customer (CustomerId, Name) values (2, 'Mary')
insert into @Customer (CustomerId, Name) values (3, 'David')

insert into @Order (OrderId, CustomerId) values (1, 1)
insert into @Order (OrderId, CustomerId) values (2, 1)
insert into @Order (OrderId, CustomerId) values (3, 1)
insert into @Order (OrderId, CustomerId) values (4, 2)
insert into @Order (OrderId, CustomerId) values (5, 2)
insert into @Order (OrderId, CustomerId) values (6, 3)

----select * from @Customer
----select * from @Order

/* Actual Query that would add the OrderId from @Order table as a comma separated list against relevant Customer */
SELECT Customer.CustomerId as CustomerId, Customer.Name,
        (
        SELECT   Convert(varchar(1), O.OrderId) + ','
        FROM     @Order AS O
        WHERE    O.CustomerId = Customer.CustomerId
        ORDER BY O.OrderId
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ) AS OrderList
FROM   @Customer AS Customer
```

Comment: Seriously @Ali .NET, Salute , you saved my day , thanks lot , that was exactly what i was trying to do .

Answer (score 0):

Well, i can't give you a complete answer, but i can tell you how to solve it. Try to use Common Table Expressions (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx).

With this you can join to your own resultset, where you make a recursive loop to solve this issue.

Hope it helps you